# visual studio 2019　edmxファイルがER図で表示されない

Tags: visual-studio

visual studio 2019にてedmxファイルをER図で表示したいのですが、コードで表示されてしまいます。
どなたかedmxファイルをER図での表示方法のご教授をお願いします。

Comment: このページ [Visual Studio の Entity Framework のツール](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/data-tools/entity-data-model-tools-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) の注意に **このページで説明されている Entity Framework のツールは、EF Core ではサポートされていない .edmx ファイルを生成するために使用されます。** とあり、[Entity Framework を取得する](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/ef6/fundamentals/install?source=recommendations) に **Visual Studio のカスタム インストールを実行する場合は、\[Entity Framework 6 Tools\] という項目が選択されていることを確認する必要があります。** とあります。Visual Studio Installer の「変更」の「個別のコンポーネント」でそれが選択されてインストールされているかどうか確認してみてください。

Comment: あと書かれている版数が非常に古いですが、こちら [Creating the ADO.NET Entity Data Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs#creating-the-adonet-entity-data-model) とこちら [Modifying the ADO.NET Entity Data Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs#modifying-the-adonet-entity-data-model) に .edmx の拡張子のファイルを扱っている記述が有ります。

Answer (score 0):

何を言ってるのかよくわかりませんが、EF6 で SQL Server の既存の DB から Visual Studio の ADO.NET Entity Data Model ウィザードで EDM を作ったのであれば、作業が完了した時点で表示されるはずです。以下の記事の (1) ～ (10) の手順を見てください。

スキャフォールディング機能
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2017/07/23/creating-controller-and-view-in-mvc-using-scaffolding-function.aspx

EF6 の Code Fisrt でコンテキストクラスとエンティティクラスを作ったのなら以下の記事のツールで表示できます。

Entity Framework 6 Power Tools
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2020/08/19/entity-framework-6-power-tools-community-edition.aspx